# Transform dictionary_tree into a list of tuple

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have this dictionary_tree:

```py
dictinary_tree =
  {'hello':
    {
     'hey': ['water', 'lumos', 'sos', 'lock', 'LORD'],
     'shield': ['key', 'crime', 'del', 'rem', 'LORD']
    },
   'prime': ['r4g', 'hey', 'p0b', 'red', 'power', 'GREEN87'],
   'zetaman': ['harry', 'qwerty', 'olly', 'spider', 'crazy', 'GREEN87']
  }
```

I want this result:

```py
[
  ('hello hey water lumos sos lock', 'LORD'),
  ('hello shield key crime del rem', 'LORD'),
  ('prime r4g hey p0b red power', 'GREEN87'),
  ('zetaman harry qwerty olly spider crazy', 'GREEN87')
]
```

The solution must not make use of external libraries. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: It's not very clear to me why the tuples are split at the particular places they are.

Comment: I suggest using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to figure out if every value is a `dict` or a `list`, and recursion to process the subdicts. I assume you already know how to iterate over a simple dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is actually what you're looking for, but the general approach is going to be to recursively descend the structure, accumulating the keys as you descend:

```
def flatten_tree(obj, prefix=[]):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return " ".join(prefix + obj[:-1]), obj[-1]
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return [flatten_tree(v, prefix + [k]) for k, v in obj.items()]
    raise TypeError("not sure what to do with scalar values")
```

```
>>> flatten_tree({'hello': {'hey': ['water', 'lumos', 'sos', 'lock', 'LORD'], 'shield': ['key', 'crime', 'del', 'rem', 'LORD']}, 'prime': ['r4g', 'hey', 'p0b', 'red', 'power', 'GREEN87'], 'zetaman': ['harry', 'qwerty', 'olly', 'spider', 'crazy', 'GREEN87']})
[[('hello hey water lumos sos lock', 'LORD'), ('hello shield key crime del rem', 'LORD')], ('prime r4g hey p0b red power', 'GREEN87'), ('zetaman harry qwerty olly spider crazy', 'GREEN87')]
```